# How do I adapt a kernel module to get past `no symbol version for module_layout`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Suppose I have some Linux kernel running with root access. There are also some existing modules present for this kernel. I want to be able to build my own kernel modules for it, but there are problems:

- No exact kernel source code available (although there is approximate one);
- No exact `.config` available (although there is approximate one);
- - No `/proc/config.gz`;
- - `scripts/extract-ikconfig` fails;
- [extract-symvers.py](https://github.com/glandium/extract-symvers) fails;
- Forced module loading fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I was specifying wrong kernel offset to extract-symvers.py.

With `extract-symvers.py -B 0xc0008000 zImage` it produced the correct `Module.symvers` file and my module loaded and worked successfully.

I'm still looking where I supposed to find `0xc0008000` - I've tried it by chance after failing with numberous other base addresses...

Comment: Run `grep '\.init' /var/log/dmesg`. It outputs something like `.init : 0xc0ac5000 - 0xc0b00000`. The first number is the kernel base address.

Comment: On my laptop kernel this grep fails to find anything. There are multiple lines like `init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff]` hovewer, with various addresses. On Android `kernel.dmesg_restrict` seems to be activated...